# Ggplot2 facets: put y-axis of the right hand side panel on the right side

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, axes, facet-wrap

I'm trying to make a facetted plot with two panels - left and right. The variable on the x-axis is continuous, and the variable on the y-axis is discrete, with relatively long labels. I would like to put the y-axis of the right hand side plot on the right side (and keep the y-axis of the left hand side left), so that the two panels are not split apart by the y-axis labels of the right hand side plot.

I've tried a couple of different workaround (e.g. `cowplot`) but I can't get anything that I would be satisfied with, because I also need a legend in my plot.

This is what I want to do:
  [image]

Here's a reprex:

```
library(tidyverse)

region <- sample(words, 20)
panel <- rep(c(0, 1), each = 10)
value <- rnorm(20, 0, 1)

df <- tibble(region, panel, value)

ggplot(df, aes(value, region)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ panel, scales = 'free_y')
```

Thank you!

Comment: I suspect you'll need to use `cowplot` or `grid` graphics to combine two separate plots (not faceted), where you explicitly control the y-axis location on one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution lacks flexibility for cases with more than 2 plots but it does the job for your case. The idea is to generate the plots separately and combine the plots into a list. The `ggplot` function call contains an `if else` function for the `scale_y_discrete` layer which puts the y-axis either on the left-hand or right-hand side depending on the value of `panel`. We use `gridExtra` to combine the plots.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)

region <- sample(words, 20)
panel <- rep(c(0, 1), each = 10)
value <- rnorm(20, 0, 1)

df <- tibble(region, panel, value)

panel <- sort(unique(df$panel))
plot_list <- lapply(panel, function(x) {
  ggplot(data = df %>% filter(panel == x), 
         aes(value, region)) +
         geom_point() +
         if (x == 0) scale_y_discrete(position = "left") else scale_y_discrete(position = "right")
})

do.call("grid.arrange", c(plot_list, ncol = 2))
```

You can leave the `facet_wrap(~ panel, scales = 'free_y')` layer and you will retain the strips at the top in the plot.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Code updated to remove x-axis from the individual plots and add text at the bottom location of the grid plot; added a second `if else` to suppress the y-axis title in the right hand plot. Note that the `if else` functions need to be enclosed by curly brackets (did not know that either :-) but it makes sense):

```
plot_list <- lapply(panel, function(x) {
  ggplot(data = df %>% filter(panel == x), aes(x = value, y = region)) +
         geom_point() +
         theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
         facet_wrap(. ~ panel) +
         {if (x == 0) scale_y_discrete(position = "left") else scale_y_discrete(position = "right")} +
         {if (x == 1) theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())}
})

do.call("grid.arrange", c(plot_list, ncol = 2, bottom = "value"))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Any ideas what to do to get only 1 x-axis title (and potentially legend)?

Comment: Check the vignette for `gridExtra` [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html) . It has functions to annotate the plot in various ways/

Comment: Surrpress the x-axis title in the individual plots by adding this theme: `theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())`. You can then create a title at the bottom of the plot by: `do.call("grid.arrange", c(plot_list, ncol = 2, bottom = "value"))`